# Wordpress manually installed on a remote server

Tags: installation

[I followed all these steps](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress#Famous_5-Minute_Install) but I can access my web site only as an administrator. The pages that I create inside the wordpress web app are not being shown from a browser or I can't find their exact link or something... Why is that so? (I have never installed a wordpress on a remote server before).

Answer (score 2):

Do this.

1. upload fresh wordpress on your remote server or install it from the cpanel.
2. then create a database.
3. then export all the table and data from the local database and import it in to the remote database (if the tables is exist in remote database then drop it.)
4. then go to the tabel wp_options and find the 'siteurl' and change the url to your remote url and then find 'home' and change the url to your remote url
5. then you have to change database name, username, password, and host in wp-congif.php file.
6. now upload all you themes and plugin in the fresh wordpress on remote server.

now run the live site.

if wordpress ask you to update the site then do it. it will not affect to your data.
thats it.

Comment: I have the remote database with the values for siteurl and home being the same, that is the folder blog but when I insert the siteurl to the browser it appears nothing.

Comment: ohh ya sorry then you have to change database name, username, password, and host in wp-congif.php file.

Comment: sorry, but i've done these changes to wp-config, too. but the problem remains...

Comment: can u give me your site url??